# How to do push code to a second and separate GitHub repository in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, github, repository

I'm stumped.

My project has it's original GitHub repository.

I will have to push the Android project to a second repository.

How to do push code to a second and separate GitHub repository in Android Studio?

I see hints that it's possible, but I don't know how to initiate to new repository.

Regards,

Comment: Create a second remote and push (command line) - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ - look at steps 8/9 specifically, you will already (probably) have a remote called "origin" so just choose another name for the remote for the 2nd, and when pushing, after you have 2 remotes, just choose which one to push to.  I do this sometimes when I have a github and bitbucket repo for the same codebase

Answer (score 5):

You can do so by either editing or adding remote URL from terminal.

To add:

```
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

To edit:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then you can push to another remote repository.

In Android studio, you can press Ctrl+Shift+K and choose where to push the commits.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Go to the android project directory and open terminal then.

1.git init

2.git remote add bitbucket https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git (bitbucket is name i have given. you can use anything like origin2 etc.)

3.git add .

4.git commit -m "first commit"

5.git push -f bitbucket master